# How could i get value of such a key in php

Tags: php, arrays

Following is my array.

```
Array
(
    [18] => 2
    [22] => 5
)
```

Now i want to get value by key

for example if my key is `18` then return 2 and if key is `22` then 5

i tried following way but not getting value of such key

```
if (array_key_exists("18",$mainQty)) {
  echo "yes";
}
```

Please help me how could i get value of such a key.

Comment: you are not displaying value here

Comment: Do you get a ``yes``?

Comment: I don't know how to do it pleas help me

Comment: You can check key and get value [like this](https://eval.in/1048525)

Answer (score 1):

You are not indexing in the array, just echoing "yes". Try it like this:

```
$mainQty = [
    18 => 2,
    22 => 5
];
if (array_key_exists("18",$mainQty)){
    echo $mainQty[18]; // 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can echo below code for the value.

```
echo $array[$key];
```

`$key` is the key name.

`$array` is the array which contains they keys and its values.

Useful link: [`PHP Array`](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say this is your array

```
Array
(
    [18] => 2
    [22] => 5
)

$your_array[18] = "2";
$your_array[22] = "5";
```

you can get the value by giving the key

```
echo $your_array[22];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if(isset($mainQty[18])&&!empty($mainQty[18])){
   echo "yes";
}
?>
```

Comment: _Now i want to get value by key
for example if my key is 18 then return 2 and if key is 22 then 5_ Not `yes`   . . . . ___Not my downvote___ _A little harsh on a new guy_